# UITabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes not working inside UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I was successfully changing the UITabBarItem's text color using the following code in its first viewController's viewDidLoad

```
    [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   [self colorWithHexString:@"ffffff"], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                   nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIColor *titleHighlightedColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"ffffff"];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                   titleHighlightedColor, UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                   nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

But then I had to change the first viewController inside the tabBarController to a navigationController. Now I am putting the same code in the first viewController of the navigationController but it is not changing the text color of UITabBarItem.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the code into your `navigationController`'s

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Or move the code just after your  `navigationController` init.